# Neo4J Graph Schema Design for User/Category/Work Nodes

Tags: database-design, graph, neo4j, cypher

Here is what I need help from Neo4J Graph Design Gurus:

**PROBLEM:**

We have following nodes in the system.

```
NODE TYPE 1: USER{id, name, dob, address, interests (fk: CATEGORY{id})}
NODE TYPE 2: CATEGORY{id, name, Specialities:Array of }
NODE TYPE 3: WORK{id, type, name, address}

 If (USER) -> [SPECIALIZES {stream:'computers'}] -> (WORK)
```

The Relationship 'SPECIALIZES' property 'stream' actual values depends on CATEGORY the USER belongs.

I.e. each CATEGORY can have a BAG of Streams and USER can SPECIALIZES in one/more of the "streams"

**Every time there is a Relationship [Specializes] established between USER and WORK, the value of "steam" needs to be a valid value from NODE: CATEGORY.Specialities.array[index]. Challenge is how can one store repository of possible "streams" per CATEGORY in Neo4J**

Is my design right?

[image]
Appreciate your guidance on the correct design if this is not looking right.

Comment: Can you somehow draw a picture?

Comment: Perhaps you can explain in words of the original business domain?

Comment: Just added,please let me know if you need further details.

Answer (score 0):

So your "Work" is a company?

I would do:

```
(:Person)-[:WORKS_IN]->(:Employment)
(:Employment)-[:HAS_CATEGORY]->(:Category)-[:NEEDS_SKILLS]->(:Skill)
(:Person)-[:HAS_SKILLS]->(:Skill)
(:Employment)-[:IN_COMPANY]->(:Company)
```

[image]